# PHP HTML 5 Table loop

Tags: php, sql, html, t-sql

Good Afternoon,

I am using the following software:

PHP Version 5.6
HTML5
sqlsrv_query

I am currently writing tables out as such:

```
<?php
// Return Results
$sql = "select warehouse,product from table1";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );  

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<!-- Create table head -->
<table>

<th>Warehouse</th><th>Product</th>

<?php 
// Create table body 
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
echo 
  "<tr>
  <td>".
  $row['warehouse'].
  "</td><td>".
  $row['product'].
  "</td>
  </tr>"
  ;
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

I'm wondering two things...

1. Is it possible to loop through the columns names to create the table head with a loop statement instead of manually typing each column name?
2. Is it possible to loop through the row names without specifying each row name?

I'm completely new to PHP so if I've written anything backwards/not efficiently then please let me know!

Thanks,

Comment: You can do that using with sqlsrv_get_field function http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php or check the doc and fetch the array in associative way. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-fetch-array-parameters

Comment: what you've done is somewhat correct. Everything is possible, you just have to understand how things work. you are looping through $row which is an array. You already know that you can make a loop with an array, so simply use a `foreach` on your `$row` element and try to get things to work. You will be able to fetch the keys and the values of the array, so you have everything to build your entire table automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an array of column names at the beginning:

```
$columns = array('warehouse', 'product');
```

Then you can use those columns for each part: query, headers, and body rows.

```
// Return Results
$sql = 'SELECT ' . implode(', ', $columns) . ' FROM table1';
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );  

// Create table head
echo '<table><thead><tr>';
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo '<th>' . ucfirst($column) . '</th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

// Create table body 
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row[$column]) . '</td>';
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```